# How can I define (or emulate) multi level data structure in Ansible inventory file?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I want to create multi-level data in an Ansible .ini file, and then loop over it.

For example (non-working psuedo code):

ini file:

```
hosts=[ host1=10.1.2.3, host2=10.4.5.6, ...]
```

task file:

```
- name: Test hosts loop
  debug:
     msg: "item {{item}} = {{item.key}} + {{ item.value }}"
  loop: "{{ hosts }}"
```

That doesn't work, and I can't see a good way to do it using Ansible data structures.

I don't mind if the task file gets a little bit complicated, but I need to keep the .ini file simple enough for people who aren't Ansible experts to be able to edit it.

Is there a good and simple way to do this?

There are various solutions around, but they all seem brainbreakingly complicated.

The best I've been able to come up with is:

ini file:

```
hosts=["host1=1.2.3.4","host2=4.5.6.7",...]
```

task file:

```
- name: Test hosts loop
  debug:
     msg: "item {{item}} = {{ item | regex_replace('=.*') }} +  {{ item | regex_replace('.*=') }}"
  loop: "{{ hosts }}"
```

And it works:

```
TASK [Test playbook: Test hosts loop] **********************************************
ok: [testhost] => (item=host1=1.2.3.4) => {
    "msg": "item host1=1.2.3.4 = host1 +  1.2.3.4"
}
ok: [testhost] => (item=host2=4.5.6.7) => {
    "msg": "item host2=4.5.6.7 = host2 +  4.5.6.7"
}
```

But is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Switch your inventory to yaml and/or define your varrs in separate `group_vars/host_vars` files?

Comment: Am trying to keep the .ini file simple enough for people to just use it, without having to learn yaml. Also a consideration is that the upstream is .ini.

Answer (score 1):

Base reference for the below examples: [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html)

Switch those vars declarations to yaml, ini format is not handy at all for that.

I am voluntarily explicit declaring the hosts below. You can omit redundant declarations if you wish.

In a nutshell:

## All-in-one yaml inventory

`inventories/example/hosts.yaml`

```yaml
---
all:
  # These will be applied to all hosts in inventory
  # except implicit localhost
  vars:
    my_dict1:
      key1: toto
      key2:
        complicated1: yeah
        complicated2: bah
  hosts:
    host1:
      # These will be applied to host1 only
      a_specific_dict:
        this:
          can:
            go:
              very: deep
    # The remaining host to not have specific vars here
    host2:
    host3:

some_group:
  # These will be applied to the group `some_group` only
  vars:
    do_something_list:
      - name: laundry
        activate: yes
      - name: clean-up
        activate: false
  hosts:
    # No need to recap previous vars if defined elsewhere
    # I prefer declaring all my host with their vars 
    # explicitly in the `all` group for clarity.
    host1:
    host3:
```

## Tidy-up: structured inventory

Same as above using good practices. We modify the host file to contain only the hosts/groups information:

`inventories/example/hosts.yaml`

```yaml
---
all:
  hosts:
    host1:
    host2:
    host3:

some_group:
  hosts:
    host1:
    host3:
```

Note that in this case, an ini file would still be very legible. Here is the alternative `inventories/example/hosts.ini`

```
host1
host2
host3

[some_group]
host1
host3
```

Now place the vars in dedicated yaml files.

In `inventories/example/group_vars/all.yml`

```yaml
---
my_dict1:
  key1: toto
  key2:
    complicated1: yeah
    complicated2: bah
```

In `inventories/example/group_vars/some_group.yml`

```yaml
---
do_something_list:
  - name: laundry
    activate: yes
  - name: clean-up
    activate: false
```

And in `inventories/example/host_vars/host1.yml`

```yaml
---
a_specific_dict:
  this:
    can:
      go:
        very: deep
```

Comment: On the one hand, my question was: "how do I do this without changing my .ini file to a different format?"  On the other hand, maybe: "You really should change the .ini file to a different format, painful as that might be" is the correct answer. So even though this isn't really the answer I wanted, I've upvoted it. Thanks.